# PHP values get added twice in array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have been struggling with this problem for the past few hours.
Basically, for school, I have to make a shopping cart using the $_SESSION variable in PHP. What I wanted to do was to add a value to the $_SESSION['cart'] array with a `$_GET` statement, but every time I do this, the values get added twice. 

The first value is added right away, but I only see the second value when I refresh the page, or add a new item. 
Lets say I add Cheese the first time, when my page loads I see a list with one item: Cheese 
When I add Butter and my page reloads, my list show 3 items: Cheese, Cheese and Butter. 
When I reload the page (without the GET statement) My list shows 4 items: Cheese, Cheese, Butter and Butter. 

I have tried adding echoes after each line to check if something happened twice, but I can't find the solution.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $products = array("Cheese", "Butter");

    if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_GET['addToCart'])) {
            $item = $_GET['addToCart'];
            if($item == "c") {
                session_destroy();
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
            }
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Create a table with the contents of $products -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Add</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product ?></td>
            <td><a href="?addToCart=<?php echo $product ?>">Add to cart</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
<!-- Create an unordered list to check the contents of $_SESSION['cart'] -->
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart) {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo $cart ?></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

After looking at the comment of towr on my post, I managed to solve my problem. I had to remove the `else` statement after `if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {}`. This solved the problem for me. The thing is that I added that later, when the problem was already there. 
Since I can't post a reply on my own question and vote that as the solution because of my reputation I had to do it this way.

Comment: When I copy-paste this to my local WAMP, nothing ever goes in the cart. Because it always takes the first branch of the `if`. When I fix that, I don't have a duplicate problem. I get another of whichever I clicked in the cart.

Comment: Now that I have copied and pasted this code and used it again, by removing the 'else' statement that belongs to if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) everything seems to work. I don't know what may have caused this, since I added that else statement when my problem was already there. Well, thanks to everyone for the quick help, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the item as the KEY in your cart:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item] = true;
```

This way, no matter how often you add (say) Cheese to the cart, you just overwrite what was there before, and end up with only one cheese in the cart.

Later on you'd retrieve the items with:

```
$selected_items = array_keys($_SESSION['cart']); // 'Cheese'
```

Comment: This would solve his duplicate problem, but I believe if he clicked on the same product twice (on different pageloads), he would end up with only 1 of them in the cart. Might not be needed, but felt like pointing it out.

Comment: But isn't this just a workaround? He clearly has problems with filtering the correct get-vars or building a good method for managing the card. Good point though.

Comment: @EduardLuca: easy enough to fix: `$_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['itemID']] += $_GET['amount'];`

Comment: @MarcB: But now he has the same problem again. On "reload" the amount gets added a second time.

Comment: change to a POST-redirect-GET pattern instead

Comment: From my point of view, every time the page gets re-loaded after an item has been added, this item will be re-added to the cart infinite, since its name is still present in the query string. Only once a new item will be added, this loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use: `array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$item);` instead of the `$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;`. Using that I did not see the same behavior you were describing.

You can still add multiple cheese ofcourse, so the idea of Marc B to use `$_SESSION['cart'][$item] = true;` is very practical when using a counter instead of true.